# Spring @Async annotated method blocks when calling itself

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

In my software I use `@Async` to call a certain method from a `Bean` in the background, on `Tomcat` startup, and this works as expected.

But, under some defined circumstances, what the method does is failing, and the method `myUtil.connect()` calls itself then to try again.

The basic code looks as follows.

The bean definition:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import package.MyService;

@Bean(initMethod = "init", destroyMethod = "destroy")
MyService myService() {
    MyService bean = new MyService();
    return bean;
}
```

And the MyService bean:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyService {

    @Inject
    private MyUtil         myUtil;

    @Async
    public void init() {
        myUtil.connect();
    }
}
```

I have tried annotating the method `connect()` also with `@Async` believing, since it calls itself, `@Async` would make it run in background as well, with no success.

Is there a way to assure subsequent calls to `connect()` "remain" in the background ?

**Edit:**

Would it be working to make `connect()` a wrapper around a function which does the real work? This way `connect()` would just be called once, and the wrapped function would call itself in case of failure.

Comment: Which method calls itself? And where and what calls `init()`?

Comment: `@ASync` is probably using a proxy and internal call are not proxied.

Comment: Does `connect()` call itself? What do you expect to happen? What actually happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The working solution for my requirement goes like this:

First I had to add `@EnableAsync` to my root context configuration class (which is the configuration class that creates the `MyService` bean).

Then I moved the `@Async` annotation from the `MyService` to the `MyUtils` class.

MyService class:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyService {

    @Inject
    private MyUtil         myUtil;


    public void init() {
        myUtil.connect();
    }
}
```

MyUtil class:

```
@Component
public class MyUtil {

    @Async
    public void connect() {}

}
```

The documentation at http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-async gave the necessary hint:

> To asynchonously initialize Spring beans you currently
>   have to use a separate initializing Spring bean that invokes the
>   @Async annotated method on the target then.