# Spring Boot - How to test @Async method throwing an exception in Mockito

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, testing, mockito

I am calling `@Async` method in one of my service methods, and now I am trying to simulate the situation when `@Async` method throws exception in the background, to assert that the caller method continues executing normally despite of asynchronously thrown exception.

Initially inside the test, I tried mocking the exception being thrown:

```
when(myAsyncServiceMock.myAsyncMethod(...some arguments...).thenThrow(new RuntimeException("failed to complete asynchronous method"));
```

but in that case, the caller method behaves as if the runtime exception was thrown in the main thread, not asynchronously.

Does Mockito have a way of specifying that the exception in `thenThrow(...)` is supposed to be thrown asynchronously, rather than in the main thread?

UPD. This is the class in which the async method (from autowired bean) gets called:

```
@Log4j2
@Service
@Setter
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.profiles")
public class MyService {

  @Autowired private MyAsyncUtil asyncUtil;

  public void myMethod1() {
    myMethod2();    
  }

  public void myMethod2() {
    asyncUtil.myAsyncMethod();
  }       

}
```

and this is `MyAsyncUtil` class with method annotated as `@Async`:

```
@Component
@Log4j2
public class MyAsyncUtil {

  @Async
  public Void myAsyncMethod() {
    // do something
  } 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`@Async` is a Spring framework annotation - if the method call is performed within the Spring context (between Spring beans), the method may be intercepted and ran on a thread different than the thread of the original caller. If the method is called outside of the Spring context, the `@Async` annotation is ignored and the method is executed on the same thread as the caller.

You can write a test involving Spring and verify the behaviour like this:

```java
@SpringBootTest
class TestedClassSpringTest {

    @MockBean
    SomeService someService;
    @Autowired
    TestedClass testedClass;

    @Test
    void test() {
        var exception = new RuntimeException("test error");
        when(someService.doStuff())
                .thenThrow(exception);

        ThrowingCallable methodCall = () -> testedClass.execute();

        assertThatNoException()
                .isThrownBy(methodCall);
    }
}
```

You will see in the console that the exception is actually thrown and logged, but the original call is not interrupted because of the exception as it operates on another thread. If you wanted, you could also verify for example if the `AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler` was called (using `Mockito.verify` method), but in such case you have to remember that the call is performed on a different thread than the main thread, so using a library such as [Awaitility](https://www.baeldung.com/awaitility-testing) may be required to avoid flaky tests (main thread could finish running before the async thread).
Note: `assertThatNoException` is a method from the [AssertJ library](https://assertj.github.io/doc/).

Another way to simulate the asynchronous execution in the test could be simply creating the new thread yourself, mimicking the Spring behaviour:

```java
class TestedClassVanillaTest {

    SomeService someService = mock(SomeService.class);
    TestedClass testedClass = new TestedClass(someService);

    @Test
    void test() {
        var exception = new RuntimeException("test error");
        when(someService.doStuff())
                .thenThrow(exception);

        ThrowableAssert.ThrowingCallable methodCall = () -> {
            new Thread(() -> testedClass.execute())
                    .start();
        };

        assertThatNoException()
                .isThrownBy(methodCall);
    }
}
```

The disadvantage of this approach is the fact that the `@Async` annotation is not required for this to work - if it's removed in the future, the test would still pass. I would advise not to use this approach since it simply tests the fact that an exception thrown in a different thread is not caught by the main thread, which is a Java truism. Still - the tests helps to understand how Spring does what it does "behind the curtains".

---

I have prepared [a GitHub repository](https://github.com/Jonarzz/stack-overflow/commit/7f3765353e4d476ba9d336812578d20188b0d454) - I verified both tests and they pass.

Comment: oh, one thing: when I put `@Async` annotation on the method `execute()` (in `TestedClass`) instead of `doStuff()` (in `SomeService`) just like the way you did in your sample code, it doesn't actually run asynchronously. It only runs asynchronously if I annotate `doStuff()` instead of `execute()` but in that case the test fails

Comment: and the reason of why I annotate `doStuff()` instead of `execute()` is because I followed instructions on this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465351/spring-async-annotated-method-blocks-when-calling-itself

Comment: at the moment I am bypassing this, by annotating both `execute()` and `doStuff()` but not sure if this is the best way of dealing with it

Comment: Could you show both those classes (especially annotations used)? I'd assume either `TestedClass` is not a bean, the method is not called from a Java bean or is called from the same class, or is private or final.

Comment: I posted them at the bottom of my question. That is the only way I could make it run asynchronously. If I remove `MyAsyncUtil`, annotate `myMethod2` with `@Async` and move all statements from `myAsyncMethod` into `myMethod2`, it blocks

Comment: You can find an explanation [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async#the-async-annotation) - "self-invocation doesn't work because it bypasses the proxy and calls the underlying method directly". The `@Async` method has to be called from another bean object. For better understanding of the proxying mechanism, you can read [this article in the Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/aop/proxying.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies).

Comment: I've added [an example with logging](https://github.com/Jonarzz/stack-overflow/commit/d6b72e38b97c27d7bdef34b481b32334fa91a8d6) to the repo linked above, where this behavior is clearly visible (`bypassProxy` method call results in all methods called from the same thread).